# Facebook C# SDK - error on hosted site, while reading fun page access token

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, facebook, access-token

I'm using Facebook C# SDK to interact with my funpage, I wrote an ASP NET vb page that posts photo on the fun page wall, it works fine on my local machine, but I receive this error when I try to execute the page on my website:

Attempt by method 'DynamicClass.CallSite.Target(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure, System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite, System.Object)' to access type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite`1' failed.

It happens when I try to cicle the array with my page access tocken.(me/accounts)

the code below generates this error after _step = 3 :

```
    Dim app As New FacebookClient(access_token)
    _step = 1
    Dim accts As Object = app.Get("/me/accounts")
    _step = 2
    ' find the access token for the fan page
    Dim page_access_token As String
    _step = 3

    For Each acct As Object In accts.data
        _step = 4

        If acct.id = Session("page_id").ToString() Then
            _step = 5
            page_access_token = acct.access_token
            '  get_album(page_access_token);
            _step = 6
            Dim fb As New FacebookClient(page_access_token)
            _step = 7
            Session.Add("page_access_token", page_access_token)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
```

I read on the web that my hosting services has server trust level set to Medium. 
hope that someone can help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem publishing my web site to Aruba servers.
I solved it casting the dynamic object retrieved from Facebook before accessing it.

In your code you have:

```
For Each acct As Object In accts.data
```

But accts is just an object and Aruba prevent to access its .data element

Try to create classes containing all the elemnts you expect to receive from FB.

```
Public Class fbcls_accts
    Public data() As fbcls_image
End Class

Public Class fbcls_image
    Public height As Integer
    Public width As Integer
    Public source As String
End Class
```

Then use JavaScriptSerializer to convert your object to the final type:

```
result = (New JavaScriptSerializer().ConvertToType(Of fbcls_accts)(accts))
```